# Is this a double exposure?

Tags: multiple-exposure, nature

[image: Photo of plants and bees]

My wife took this pic of some plants using her Samsung Galaxy phone, and was surprised when these two bees showed on the photo. Not surprised at bees being near plants of course. But what's puzzling is that it looks like a double exposure - as if there was a single bee and an extra, more transparent image of the same bee appeared. Is that possible with a digital phone camera? Or is this just two bees?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends what you mean by "double exposure" - this is almost certainly the phone doing an attempt at [hdr](/questions/tagged/hdr); this works well if the images don't change "much" between exposures, but sometimes the HDR algorithm will just fail and come up with something like what you've seen.

Comment: HDR as automatically implemented in smart phones involves two or more exposures at different exposure values, which are then blended to avoid excessive shadow and highlight values.